# Drupal 6 website saving profile values to the user->data object instead of to the profile_fields table, how do I prevent this so I can use in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Hopefully someone is familiar enough with the Drupal 6 Profile module to help me out here. I'm looking at the code but can't make sense of it.

I've set up a bunch of profile fields in different categories and it seemed to be working fine. Then I needed to show the data in a view, but it's just not showing up...only a few fields are.

After a few hours of digging I've discovered that the profile values are being saved to the serialized "data" column in the users table, not to the profile_values table, even though the profile_fields table has fields for all of my new columns.

What's the deal with this? It's killing me...i can't seem to make sense of the logic looking at the module, if I spend the time to write a script to transfer all the data from the user->data column to the proper profile fields table then will it remain there or will it be futile.

Thanks for the help. Pretty frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally figured this out. I was really thrown for a loop since it's been working, it must be default drupal behavior to save superfluous data to the user->data object?

Anyhow, I'd used hook_user to add profile forms to the main user edit form but I neglected to run profile_save_profile explicitly on the additional fields on the update operation of hook_user. Have it working now.